# How to extract several substrings with a foor loop in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following 100 strings:

```
 [3] "Department_Complementary_Demand_Converted_Sum" 
 [4] "Department_Home_Demand_Converted_Sum"                   
 [5] "Department_Store A_Demand_Converted_Sum"                
 [6] "Department_Store B_Demand_Converted_Sum"
 ...                
 [100] "Department_Unisex_Demand_Converted_Sum"
```

Obviously I can for every string use `substr()` with different start and end values for the string indices. But as one can see, all the strings start with `Department_` and end with `_Demand_Converted_Sum`. I want to only extract what's inbetween. If there was a way to always start at index 11 from the left and end on index 21 from the left then I can just run a for loop over all the 100 strings above.

### Example

**Given input:** `Department_Unisex_Demand_Converted_Sum`

**Expected output:** `Unisex`

Comment: Can you show the expected output given the expected input shown.

Comment: @sindri_baldur - Ofcourse. Please check my edit.

Comment: `gsub("^Department_|_Demand_Converted_Sum$", "", string)` or `stringr::str_sub(string, 12, -22)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a like a classic case for lookarounds:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str, "(?<=Department_)[^_]+(?=_)")
[1] "Complementary" "Home"          "Store A"
```

Data:

```
str <- c("Department_Complementary_Demand_Converted_Sum",
         "Department_Home_Demand_Converted_Sum",
         "Department_Store A_Demand_Converted_Sum")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit()`,

```
sapply(strsplit(string, '_'), '[', 2)
# [1] "Complementary" "Home"          "Store A"
```

or `stringi::stri_sub_all()`.

```
unlist(stringi::stri_sub_all(str, 12, -22))
# [1] "Complementary" "Home"          "Store A"
```